# Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS - provisioning to restore to pre-upgrade state

Tags: rsync, ubuntu-16.04, backup-restoration

We have an ubuntu 16.04 LTS server that we wish to upgrade to 18.04. 
However if something goes wrong, we don't want to be doing a re-install of 16.04, instead we would like to be able to take a backup that can be used to restore to the original state pre-upgrade commencement.

We looked at some documentation, and `rsync` appears to be a tool of choice for this purpose. However most of the articles talk about using rysync to recover a certain file or partition, we are interested in getting the whole system back in the same state that it was before commencing the upgrade.

Any help on the tools to use for this would be appreciated.

EDIT : the server is not VPS nor virtualized but bare metal, in premise.

Answer (score 0):

https://clonezilla.org/ seems to be a viable option for backup and restore